# Residency Visa about to Expire and will travel to Russia soon

Tags: visas, russia, residency

Im on a Non Lucrative Residency Visa for Spain while I wait for my spanish citizenship (and passport) to finally be done. I plan to go to Russia now and I want to make sure they will let me back into Schengen. My Visa expires on the 6th of september and I cant get an appointment for a new visa until the one I have is already expired. (I cant as in no one can, thats how the system works)

If I go into Russia in a week and come back to Estonia/Finland say end of September, do you think they will give me problems trying to get back in? 
Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 2):

You cannot use your visa to enter the Schengen area after its expiry date. It is expired after that date and will not be accepted. The airline will simply deny boarding, and immigration officers will not accept it either if you traveled by some other means.

If you have your *Tarjeta de Identidad de Extranjero* and it is still valid, you can enter the Schengen area with that, instead of a visa. It is the red and blue card with a bull and stars above the picture.

Comment: Sorry, thats what I meant. So as long as my "Permiso de Residenci" is still valid, I should be able to get back inwithout problems? Even if it is a few days before its expiry date? Thanks again!

Comment: @FelipeBS89 Yes, you just can't return _after_ the expiry date.